# existence of finite free resolutions of finite modules over polynomial rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Theorem 2.8 in Chapter XXI of Lang's Algebra says

> Theorem 2.8. Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring. Let $x$ be a variable. If every finite $R$-module has a finite free resolution, then every finite $R[x]$-module has a finite free resolution.

Then as an application, Lang quotes a theorem by Serre:

> Theorem 2.9. If $k$ is a field and $x_1,\cdots,x_r$ are independent variables, then every finite projective module over $k[x_1,\cdots,x_r]$ is stably free, or equivalently admits a finite free resolution.

Question: it seems to me that if we apply Theorem 2.8 to the setting of Theorem 2.9, we do not need the assumption that our module is projective. In that case we have the more general statement:

(Edited after Youngsu's comment)

> If $k$ is a field and $x_1,\cdots,x_r$ are independent variables, then every finite module over $k[x_1,\cdots,x_r]$ admits a finite free resolution.

Is that right?

Comment: I don't think so. If a finitely generated module is stably free, then it is projective. However, not every finitely generated module is projective, for instance, $k$.

Comment: @Youngsu: Thanks for the comment. I will edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes thats true the proof from Lang's book applies. If k is a field then it every module is free and from theorem 2.8 (and Hilbert's basis theorem) u get inductive step. The thing is theorem 2.9 is standard step in the proof of Quillen's theorem (every finite projective module over polynomials is free) which they are proving in next chapter. Probably thats why they they are interested in this some how weaker statement.